# Mouse doesn't click but I can move it in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, 18.04

I'm a bit desperate... a few weeks ago I updated my ubuntu to 18.04 (without problems) but since today, a few hours ago my mouse stopped working. I can see it and I can also move it around, but I am not abble to click on anything...

I tried everything that I could think off...

- Rebooting
- Trying another mouse (same problem)
- updating all my drivers

Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a Driver Issue or A bug on their latest update. Don't worry about it you can update your drivers using your keyboard. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key as per as your requirement and search for "Additional Drivers" & update it. Or wait till their next Patch Update.

Answer (score 0):

What did you do before it stopped working?

Does it work after reboot on the log-in screen?

I had the same issue shortly after updating Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. The mouse suddenly stopped working when I was doing something in LibreOffice Calc. After reboot the mouse started working again until I started LibreOffice with this particular spreadsheet.

Indeed the problem was caused by LibreOffice 6.1 that I installed from PPA (see [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/08/11/install-libreoffice-6-1-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/)). After downgrading to the default 6.0.7.3 version which comes with Ubuntu 18.04 the mouse issue disappeared.